# Synchronisation of data over multiple devices

Tags: mongodb, synchronization

I have a mongo database with a collection of objects, lets say orders.

Multiple mobile devices are saving and loading orders to that collection.

When one device saves a new order to the database, all devices should sync and download new data. I want to be able to sync every 3 seconds so everyone can have latest data at every moment.

Now my problem is how to accomplish that efficiently? I do not want to load all the data, and parse it on the client side. I want to download only the missing orders.

What would be the best practice way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do a differential update.

You'll need to record the time of the last update of each device in the DB and the time of each modification to the DB.

Then you only update with the changes that occurred after the last time the device updated.

Also, one last note, sync'ing every 3 seconds will drain the battery fairly quickly. Perhaps you should consider only updating a device when the device has something to send to the server. ie send a new order, and the server response contains all new orders.

Comment: I need to update every 3 seconds because i need to have new data as close to real time as possible. Hopefully the device will be able to last 12h (ios devices)